# Sum of my ngModel elements returns NAN when formGroup.length > 1

Tags: angular, typescript

Outside my form-group i have this ngModel input:

```
<input [class.disabled]="controls[0] > 0" [(ngModel)]="produto.estoque" type="text">
```

This input show the sum of the input values inside my formgroup.

I have this form group:

```
<form [formGroup]="variacaoForm">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of variacoes.controls; let i = index;">
    <input [(ngModel)]="controls[i]" (keyup)="soma($event)" type="text" name="estoque_variacao{{i}}" formControlName="estoque_variacao">
```

I can have "N" inputs.

This is actualy my function that sum the input estoque_variacao:

```
  soma(){
    let sum = 0;

    Object.keys(this.variacaoForm.value.variacoes).map(key => {
      sum +=  +this.variacaoForm.value.variacoes[key].estoque_variacao;
    })
      this.produto.estoque = sum
    }
```

Everything works well when i follow this steps:

1. Add a new form group;
2. Fill the value in the input estoque_variacao
3. Add other form group
4. Fill the value of the second input estoque_variacao
5. The sum is show correctly in the input produto.estoque

The problem is when i follow this steps:

> 1. Add a new Form group;
> 2. Don't fill the value of the estoque_variacao of the first formGroup;
> 3. Add a new form group;
> 4. Try to fill the estoque_variacao of the first of second input of my form group returns NAN in my produto.estoque.

My function that create the formGroup:

```
createFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
         estoque_variacao: 0
}
```

How can i fix this?

**@Edit:**

Worked for me:

```
  soma(){
    let sum = 0;

    const value = this.variacaoForm.value.variacoes;

    for(const key in value){
      sum += (+value[key].estoque_variacao);
    }

    this.produto.estoque = sum
  }
```

And when i remove the formgroup i need to decrease the value of my input:

```
this.produto.estoque = this.produto.estoque - this.variacaoForm.value.variacoes[index].estoque_variacao
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use ngModel and FormControlName together. In fact, you should not use Template Driven Forms and Reactive Forms together. These are two different approaches and you need to pick one for any given situation.

Here's an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uqvcnb

Hope this helps

Comment: i know, but i don't know other way to make a formGroup sum without ngModel

Comment: You have a formGroup, you can get values from fromGroup with `variacaoForm .value` and proceed with that

Comment: I've updated the main answer with an example. Please take a look

Comment: Ok, i remove the ngModel and change my soma() function, see my edit, but when i add more than 1 formGroup and try to fill the estoque_variacao my produto_estoque still show NaN. Probably not a problem with ngModel + formControlName

Comment: i will try with your function

Comment: Thanks, you function work well, i edit my question with aditional code that work for me